# Polite or unrectified placement of the word please

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, exclamations

> I would please prefer to take both parts of the test on Monday.

Is the placement of the word *please* in this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: No, it's not. And if you're being polite, stating a preference is less polite than asking for a favor. Stating preferences is upper-status speaking to lower; asking for a favor is lower-status speaking to upper. In a question there are dozens of places where _please_ can be used, but in a statement like this, it only really goes well at the end: _.. on Monday, please._ And by the end of the sentence it's too late to remedy the politeness. Start over with a question and a mollifier: _If it's all the same to you, could I please take both parts on Monday?_

Comment: @JohnLawler, I agree that the example with *please* is not especially polite.  More like the tone of the boss telling you to please finish your report before going home for the day.  But we don't always have to be polite, do we.

Comment: We do if we want an exception to a rule; at least, it's a better idea than the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

It feels better at the end of the sentence.

> I would prefer to take both parts of the test on Monday, please.

But a rewording offers a better request.

> May I please take both parts of the test on Monday?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but I would have expressed this version if I were you:

> I humbly request you to allow me to take both parts of the test on Monday.

(You can also use *sincerely* or *kindly* instead of *humbly*)

Or this one:

> It would be my pleasure If you can allow me to take both parts of the test on Monday.

(you can also use *a delight* in place of *my pleasure*)

Comment: Well, yes, but your proposed versions are not American English.  Too flowery.

Comment: @GregLee OP didn't mention she wants American English. Also, what you call *flowery* is actually called the *norm* or *mannerism* in British English (or rather *Indian English* in my case which is influenced by the Britishers).

Comment: The OP didn't mention that she wanted a rewording either.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Yup, but instead of just saying `Yes`, I offered an elaborate answer consisting of alternatives. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: @GregLee while I agree that this is a bit more groveling than is strictly necessary, the fact that it is not AmE is completely irrelevant. This site deals with English in all its many forms and dialects and none of them is considered more or less correct than any other.

Comment: @PrahladYeri I do not believe it helps the asker as it is wrong and hides the wrong answer behind a rewording that doesn't address the issue.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен It would have certainly been wrong if I had changed the meaning in any manner. But if you look carefully, OP's sentence and my updated version mean the exact same thing. The context here is a student is expressing a desire to *take test* at a different schedule. In this light, how would my version mean anything different than the original statement? I just changed the words to make the expression more polite, that`s it!

Comment: The OP's sentence is wrong.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен It could be wrong in phonetic sounding, but *[grammatically correct](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck)*. And that`s what the OP had asked.

Comment: I believe my brain over a computer's idea of how grammar might work any time of the day or night.

Answer (score 1):

**[Please for Requests](http://esl.about.com/od/intermediate_common_mistakes/a/Please-And-Thank-You.htm)** : (ESL- about.com)

The [placements](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231952/can-i-would-please-prefer-be-grammatical) could be many.

When 'please' is used in order to make requests more polite. *It is is added to the end of polite question and is preceded by a comma*. Notice that 'please' is placed at the beginning when giving instructions to make the order a little more polite.

- May I use your telephone, please?
- Please fill in this form.

You can ask-

> Could I take both parts of the test on Monday, please?
>
> or
>
> Could I please take both parts of the test on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Please seeks permission, and it is logically incorrect to seek permission for your preference. You use please to seek permission to take the exam when you prefer.

Consider changing *I would please prefer to take both parts of the test on Monday.* to *Please may I take both parts of the test on Monday.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  "Please" goes in requests, and stating a preference for something in the listener's control is an indirect way of making a request.

Comment: _I would please prefer..._ is not used in any dialect I know of. While I did find [a hit](https://books.google.gr/books?id=sMS3JSvbiscC&pg=PT25&lpg=PT25&dq=%22I+would+please+prefer%22&source=bl&ots=mlM9_bf2E1&sig=389qxBOmB0dNY22d7mmn6IZc1gI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0Hv4VMGtHoWAU_TCgfgM&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20would%20please%20prefer%22&f=false) on Google Books for it, it is from a book whose prose can only be described as horrible and which should not be taken as indication of regular usage.

Comment: @terdon, not used in any dialect you know of?  Not the OP's dialect?  Not in my dialect?  Not in the dialects of other answerers who found it acceptable?

Comment: Um, no, just not in any that I know of. If it is accepted in one you are familiar with, I would be very interested to know which. _Please_ is associated with requests and an expression of preference is not a request. Seriously, if you know of a dialect that would use such a form please edit it into your answer. Preferably with a reference to a printed example.

Comment: @terdon, as I pointed out in my answer, an expression of preference can be used to make an indirect request (or to give an order).  You're just wrong about that.  As to whether the example is grammatical in any dialect, I hereby notify you that I find it grammatical.  That's what I meant in my answer when I wrote "Yes."

Comment: Oh, indeed, I misspoke (wrote?) there. _I'd prefer you came now_ is a request, absolutely. It's the _I would please prefer <verb>_ that seems very odd to me. I've been told it may be Indian English but that's a dialect I am not familiar with.  I posted [a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/231952/25030) about this, perhaps you would care to expand on the subject there?